# Consulta em uma coluna com valores diferentes

Tags: c#, sql-server

Em meu projeto, tenho um `SELECT` que me retorna dois nomes, mas esses nomes são diferentes. Em meu comando, preciso retornar esses dois nomes diferentes que estão na mesma coluna do banco em uma *tag* de um *xml* que estou criando.

Como que eu poderia fazer um método que reconhecesse esses dois nomes em [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) e me retornasse eles?

Do jeito que tenho aqui, ele me retorna somente um.

Vou colocar aqui meu `SELECT` pra ajudar!

```
SELECT *
FROM TabelaPessoa 
INNER JOIN TabelaRegistro ON PessoaCodCasamentoCodigo = CasamentoCodigo 
INNER JOIN LocalCasamento ON LocalCasamentoCodigo = CasamentoCodigo 
LEFT JOIN CasamentoRegime ON RegimeCodigo = CasamentoCodigo 
LEFT JOIN Infomacao ON InformacaoCodigo = CasamentoCOdigo
WHERE NomePessoa = 'Fulano' OR
      NomePessoa = 'Fulana' 
AND CodigoTipoPessoa IN (1, 7)
```

## EDIT

Códigos `C#` que tenho:

```
        try
        {
            string sqlPesquisa = "";

            sqlPesquisa = "SELECT * \n" +
            "FROM TabelaPessoa  INNER JOIN TabelaRegistro ON \n" +
            "     PessoaCodCasamentoCodigo = CasamentoCodigo INNER JOIN LocalCasamento ON \n" +
            "     LocalCasamentoCodigo = CasamentoCodigo LEFT JOIN CasamentoRegime ON \n" +
            "     RegimeCodigo = CasamentoCodigo LEFT JOIN Infomacao ON \n" +
            "     InformacaoCodigo = CasamentoCodigo \n" +
            "WHERE NomePessoa = " + tabela + " OR \n" +
            "      NomePessoa = " + tabela + " AND \n" +
            "      CodigoTipoPessoa IN (1, 7)";

            DataTable pesquisa = executarPesquisa(sqlPesquisa);

            return (pesquisa);
        }
```

Comment: Coloque o código em C# do seu método também para que alguém possa lhe ajudar.

Comment: Não vejo problema algum com o código. Acho que é o caso de fazer um [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) pra validar os dados.

Comment: Por que você faz `+ tabela +`? Você está passando o mesmo nome e comparando duas vezes da mesma forma... tem algo de errado

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez o que acontece é que na hora de me retornar os dados, digo os nomes, só me retorna um dos nomes, e repete-se ele

Comment: `+ tabela +` é o valor da tabela que quero que venha os dados!

Comment: Então. Coloque os dados no SQL Fiddle e vamos ver o que ocorre.

Comment: O complicado é que são várias tabelas que tenho aqui, e faço os `joins` nelas. São umas 4 tabelas.

Comment: O seu código tem "+ tabela +" duas vezes, ele está procurando o mesmo nome duas vezes. Além disso, como o Fernando respondeu, faltam parenteses... AND tem preferência sobre o OR. Assim, A OR B AND C é a mesma coisa que A OR (B AND C).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu comando **nunca** vai retornar dois nomes diferentes porque você está pesquisando apenas UM nome, e o nome que você esta pesquisando vem de uma variável chamada `tabela`. Seu comando devia ser:

```
 where 
     ( NomePessoa = '" + Nome_1 + "' OR NomePessoa = '" + Nome_2 + "' )
 AND ( CodigoTipoPessoa in (1,7) )
```

onde

```
 Nome_1 = 'Fulano'
 Nome_2 = 'Fulana'
```

E somente irá lista o Fulano ou a Fulana que o `CodigoTipoPessoa` estiver entre 1 e 7

Answer (score 1):

Eu recomendaria separar o nome em duas colunas no seu banco de dados. Uma alternativa, considerando dois nomes:

```
string doisNomes = "Fulano Sicrano";
string[] arrayDeDoisNomes = doisNomes.Split(' ');
string nomeUm = arrayDeDoisNomes[0]; // aqui está "Fulano"
string nomeDois = arrayDeDoisNomes[1]; // aqui está "Sicrano"
```

O método Split recebe um char (ou uma string) como delimitador, um caracter que identifica o "corte". No exemplo acima eu utilizei um espaço em branco.